# How to install ffmpeg 4.x on debian 9?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, debian, vps, directadmin

I have VPS. I use directadmin on da-debian 9, php 7.2. I want to install the ffmpeg 4.x library

How to do it? I have not found any specific guides on the internet.